# Verification failure PKCS1_PSS verifier object for Signature signed with RSA 3k and sha384.[Crypto python module]

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to verify the signature file(binary file). I have RSA3k public key and the hash algorithm used is SHA384 Padding shceme used is: PSS. I used Crypto.Signature module in python. I am creating a verifier object in-order to verify the signature -->** PKCS1_PSS.new(key)**.

Below the simple code, verify_signature function takes three parameters public_key_file, message_file and signature_file and returns whether the signature is authentic or not.

```
Code:
def verify_signature(public_key_file, message_file, signature_file):
    # Read the public key from the PEM file
    # with open(public_key_file, 'rb') as f:
    #     key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
    # construct key using the modulus file
    with open(os.path.join('projectkeys', 'exponent.fws'), 'rb') as f: # open exponent file
        data = f.read()
    e = int(data.hex(), 16)
    with open(public_key_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    n = int(data.hex(), 16)
    key = RSA.construct((n, e))
    with open(message_file,'rb') as f2:
        message = f2.read()
    with open(signature_file,'rb') as f3:
        signature = f3.read()
    h = SHA384.new(message)
    # Verify the signature using the verifier and the hashed message

    # mgf = lambda x,y : MGF1(x,y,SHA384.new(message))
    verifier = PKCS1_PSS.new(key)

    if verifier.verify(h, signature):
        return "The signature is authentic."
    else:
        return "The signature is not authentic."
```

- I tried both ways i. to read the key from the file and ii. constructed key using modulus(n) and exponent(e) values.
- This verifier object is verifying correctly if the key is RSA2k and sha256. I tried to explore the mgf(mask generation function) and pass the values appropriately, but I am getting incorrect output.

If anyone has an idea why this code is failing will be really helpful. Or sharing any alternate way of verifying the signature for example using openssl.

Thanks,

Comment: Why verification works in one case (2048/SHA256) and not in the other (3072/SHA384) is probably easier to analyze if the code used for signing is known. Have you considered that in the failed case, the private and public keys may simply not be related?

Comment: I analyzed the code that is used for signing it looks prettily similar kind of code. But I'm not sure do I need to pass any additional parameters to the verifier object?

Comment: [PSS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.1) must be configured for verification with the same parameters that were used for signing.